# how to create regular expression for phone numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate 10 digit number which should start with `91` or `+91`

```
   var expr = new Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");
```

This here only matches 10 digit which start with 9.

input:  919234521098,9876543210;+919876543211;919876543212

op :919234521098,+919876543211;919876543212

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any examples of things this should match / decline?

Comment: If you visualize your regexp it kind of get's clear. [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-htMThQgUVf2ZiMe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This expression works](https://regex101.com/r/cC2qD9/1):

```
\+?91\d{8}
```

What it does:

- `\+?`: an option `+` (`\` escapes the `+`. The `?` makes it optional)
- `\d{8}`: 8 digits

Comment: This doesn't account for the optional spacing `(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1})` (neither do the other answers)..

Comment: @Sayse: Where is that in the question?

Comment: in the op's provided regex

Comment: @Sayse: Okay. I just saw that as a copy/paste from a sample that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\+?91\d{8}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should do the trick

```
\+?91\s?\d{8}
```

It will match both +9112345678, 9112345678, +91 12345678 and 91 12345678

Explanation:

- +?91 will match 91 or +91(note the ?, it will make the character before optional)
- \s? will allow to have a space after 91
- \d{8} matches 8 digits

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex:

https://regex101.com/r/mB4rX2/1

```
^\+?91[0-9]{8}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It would match a 10 digit mobile number starting with either +91 or 91.

```
^[+]*91\d{10}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[+91]+\d{8}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`^\+?91[7,8,9]{1}[0-9]{9}$`
This will check for + is there or not. Then for 91 and then first digit will be between 7,8,9 and then last 9 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSMSMNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                        ControlToValidate="txtSMSMNo" ErrorMessage="Enter Mobile No"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatortxtMob" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
                        ControlToValidate="txtSMSMNo" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Mobile No." ValidationGroup="Valid"
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[789]\d{9}$"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
used this code solve your problem


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="RegularExpressionValidatortxtMob" 
runat="server"
SetFocusOnError="true"
ControlToValidate="txtSMSMNo" 
ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Mobile No."
ValidationGroup="Valid" 
ForeColor="Red"
ValidationExpression="^[789]\d{9}$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```